# Custom arrayadapter for listview with image

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So I am following the tutorial [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/) so I can images to my listview. The problem is in this tutorial the images are already installed so for getting the image it is saved as an int like so:

```
private int imageId;
private String title;
private String desc;

public RowItem(int imageId, String title, String desc) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
}
public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}
```

But I am getting the images from a server where it is coming to the app as a string and then be converted to a bitmap. The question I have is could I just change int to bitmap and everything will work out or is there something else I need to do? I don't want to work all the way through this and then it not work.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want to take a look at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader to `lazy load` your images and caching them to prevent the network freeze your UI thread.

Comment: But would it still work if I just changed it to int to bitmap. I already know the app should always get the image as a string and I'm not sure how I would implement the image loader you posted.

Comment: nope it will not work as that easy. To see an example you can follow http://sunil-android.blogspot.it/2013/09/lazy-loading-image-download-from.html I just googled for: listview universal image loader tutorial